# codeigniter get value from url

Tags: codeigniter, url

How can i recieve the value in a controller from the following URL in codeigniter

```
http://localhost/directory/c_service/get_radius/lang=123
```

controller:

```
class C_service extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
}

public function get_radius()
{

i need to get the vLUE 123 here
like,
`$value=$get['lang'];`

}
```

Thanks

Comment: what is your controller name? and What value do you intend to receive?

Comment: sorry,my controller name is "c_service" and "get_radius" is a function in controller..i need to recieve the value 123 inside the function "get_radius"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Codeigniter you can simply do

```
public function get_radius($lang)
{
   var_dump($lang); //will output "lang=123"
}
```

So your link could be simplified to `http://localhost/directory/c_service/get_radius/123` if you don't want to do something like `explode('=', $lang)` to get your value.

You should however also consider adding a default value `public function get_radius($lang=0)` if the link is opened without a parameter.

Adding more variables is as easy as `public function get_radius($lang, $other)` for `http://localhost/directory/c_service/get_radius/123/other`

Answer (score 16):

You can use:

```
<?php
$this->input->get('lang', TRUE);
?>
```

The TRUE is to turn on XSS filtering, which you do want turned on.

Check out https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html for more info.

Comment: activate XSS is useful only when you want to display the value in the user browser. Otherwise it's useless, that's the reason why by default it's not activated.

Answer (score 8):

enable url helper in config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

or load url helper in desired controller or its method

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

and then use below in controller

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

the above line will get you the first parameter, increasing value will get you parameters

```
$this->uri->segment(4);
```

will get you second and so on.

hope this helps you

Answer (score 2):

I manage it and i check it thats working 
first load the url

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

example : http://localhost/schoolmanagement/student/studentviewlist/541

if you use `$this->uri->segment(3);` you get (541) id

The above line will get you the first parameter, increasing value will get you parameters

```
$this->uri->segment(4);
```